# Existe-t-il une règle d'emploi du trait d'union avec les préfixes?

Tags: orthographe, préfixes, trait-d-union

Dans beaucoup de textes, l'emploi du trait d'union est incohérent. Par exemple, il est fréquent de voir écrit co-opération, mais aussi coopération. Cette ambiguïté est aussi prononcée avec le préfixe *re* (réévaluer/ré-évaluer, re-copier/recopier). Parfois l'emploi semble indécis : « inter-spatial », « interactif ». Parfois il est obligatoire (demi), parfois il est interdit (il paraît que c'est le cas du préfixe *re*).

Existe-t-il des règles, voire des moyens mnémotechniques, pour savoir quand utiliser le trait d'union ? Faut-il apprendre par cœur la liste des préfixes ?

Answer (score 9):

Wikipédia nous dit que.... ça dépend ! ([une page complète dédiée à l'utilisation du trait d'union avec les préfixes](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_r%C3%A8gles_d%27emploi_du_trait_d%27union_pour_les_pr%C3%A9fixes))

Mais en résumé, c’est le préfixe qui détermine s’il faut un trait d’union ou pas (avec les exceptions à la règle habituelles...).

Les préfixes suivants réclament **toujours** un trait d’union :

- après-
- mi-
- non- (sauf dans nonchalance, nonobstant, nonpareil, et dans le cas où non est suivi d’un adjectif : non linéaire)
- quasi-
- sous-

Il **ne faut pas** de trait d’union après les préfixes suivants :

- anti (sauf lorsque le deuxième élément commence par i, dans des mots composés comportant d’autres traits d’union et dans les noms géographiques),
- archi
- auto (sauf lorsque le deuxième élément commence par une voyelle et dans auto-stop et auto-stoppeur)
- bi
- bio
- brachy
- co (**donc pas de co-opération, mais plutôt une coopération**)
- ferro (sauf lorsque le deuxième élément commence par une voyelle)
- inter
- intra (sauf lorsque le deuxième élément commence par une voyelle)
- macro
- méta
- micro (sauf lorsque le deuxième élément commence par une voyelle)
- mono
- multi
- pré
- tri

Comment: J'aurais bien remplacé tes exceptions ("*sauf lorsque...*") par une règle générale valant pour tout préfixe, (sans compter qu'il ne s'agit pas de n'importe quelle voyelle). Je suggère donc : *On conserve le trait d'union (pas de soudure) lorsque le préfixe se termine par **a** ou **o** ET que l'élément préfixe commence par **i** ou **u**. Consigne fort logique puisque, dans ces cas la soudure provoquerait la disparition de la diphtongue.

Answer (score 2):

Depuis les rectifications de 1990, l'Académie préconise sans ambigüité la soudure de nombres de préfixes. On note notamment les deux règles suivantes :

— A2 : dans tous les composés de extra-, infra-, intra-, ultra- (ex. : extrafort sur le modèle de extraordinaire), comme les composés de en, sur, supra, déjà soudés. N.B. Le trait d'union est maintenu dans les mots où la soudure engendrerait une prononciation défectueuse (ex. : extra-utérin).

— A3 :  dans les composés d'éléments savants, en particulier en -o (ex. : autoécole sur le modèle de radioactif). N.B. Le trait d'union est maintenu dans les noms propres et termes géographiques où il sert à marquer une relation de coordination entre les deux termes (ex. : gréco-romain).

Les différents dictionnaires sont invités à introduire cette variante et à la retenir pour les nouveaux mots. Vous ne risquez donc pas grand-chose à souder systématiquement et à recourir à un dictionnaire en cas de doute. De toute façon, les deux graphies restent officiellement admises.